# CURL Login and then redirect using curl array method

Tags: php

So I am trying to log into a Vbulletin forum and so far all is good. It logs in and I see the message that it was successful, but then tries to redirect to the main index.php page. Basically After logging in I wan to navigate to my profile page for example `http://website.com/members/mr10.html`. Here is what I have so far.

```
<?php
$xxx = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($xxx, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://website.com/login.php?do=login',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'vb_login_username' => 'mr10',
        'vb_login_password' => '1234qwerA',
        'submit' => '',
        's' => '',
        'do' => 'login',
        'vb_login_md5password' => '',
        'vb_login_md5password_utf' => ''
    )
));
curl_exec($xxx);
curl_close($xxx);

$yyy = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($yyy, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://website.com/members/rastof.html',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'cookies.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'cookies.txt',
));
$resp = curl_exec($yyy);
curl_close($yyy);
echo $resp;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll not be redirected unless you change `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true`.

If you don't want to be redirected, just leave it as is and make another request to profile page.

Comment: When making the other request, be sure to use the same `CURLOPT_COOKIE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` so subsequent requests will recognize the session.

Comment: @Elon Than I did that but it asks me to log in again. Updated my post,